# NDepend - Unresolved .NET Assembly Error

Tags: .net, ndepend

I am trying to run NDepend on our project. Even though the solution is built and assemblies exist, there is the following error:

"Can't find the .NET assembly {AssemblyName} in specified folders. Has it been compiled properly?
Is the NDepend project missing the containing folder of the .NET aseembly?"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at directories list in NDepend Project properties > Code to Analyze > View Dir that contains .NET Assemblies, does your assembly parent dir is there? If no just add it

Comment: Yes, I can see the directory under View Directories.

Comment: Does the assembly file name have .exe or .dll extension? Are you sure it is a valid assembly?