# ndepend - Unresolved .NET assembly

Tags: .net, ndepend

I get below error for some of my libraries.

```
Error!
Unresolved .NET Assembly 

Can't find the .NET assembly {x} in specified folders. 
Has it been compiled properly? 
Is the NDepend project missing the containing folder of the .NET assembly?
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012468/ndepend-unresolved-net-assembly-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067190/cant-find-the-net-assembly-assemblyname-in-specified-folders) for a solution first.

I tried the following;

- Adding from solution which is in debug mode. Built several times.
- Adding folders of debug folder and the parent folders
- Adding assemblies by folder
- Trying all .net profiles
- Adding dll by drag & drop

Thanks

**EDIT**: why the close flag? This application error wasted my whole day. Someone could benefit from this since the actually given error is really obscure.

Answer (score 1):

This is incredible but all the problematic libraries had the letter 'I' in their names. Changing them to 'i' makes them work.

For some reason Visualndepend and vs extension both cannot recognize dll's that have this letter.

Comment: We're sorry for the time lost on this, please send us a repro at support@ndepend.com, we've never hear of such problem and would be glad to repro and fix it, thanks

Comment: Just tried a few times the letter 'I' doesn't provoque any analysis issue on our end, please send us a repro, could it be a 'I' upper case Turkish problem? even with such Turkish 'I' it works fine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_alphabet

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam just sent a mail with the requested stuff. Hope it helps.

Comment: This problem is now fixed with NDepend v2017.3